# Make buttons appear after a couple of seconds

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm making a "landing page" for my website where I put all of my exercises.
I would like to make my buttons "fade in" after a couple a seconds. How do I do this?

This is my button class: `.fadeButton`

I got this far with jquery to make it animate after couple of seconds: `$( ".fadeButton" ).delay( 6000 );`

But I don't know how to let the buttons fade in instead of showing it directly

Comment: Tried CSS animations ? You haven't post your HTML but be sure it could be done in CSS pretty easily, using `animation-delay` and `transition`

Comment: the thing i needed was animation delay!  thanks bud!

Comment: you're welcome :)

Comment: You can fade in with .fadeIn: `$(".fadeButton").delay(6000).fadeIn();`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try with this:
When the page is fully loaded, after 2 seconds you fade in (with jquery .fadeIn()) your button

```js
$(window).on('load', function() {
  $('.fadeButton').delay(2000).fadeIn()
})
```

```css
.fadeButton {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class='fadeButton'>Button</button>
```

Comment: This is what `.delay()` https://api.jquery.com/delay/ is for.  No need for a setTimeout.

Comment: Thanks you so much, we don't have any css subject in school, but i still want some sort of cool landing page :D

Answer (score 2):

In your css file say:

```
.fadeButton {
    opacity: 0;
    transition: opacity 0.5s;
}
```

In your onload section of javascript or just somewhere on page say:

```
setTimeout(function(){
    $('.fadeButton').css({'opacity':'1'})
}, 2000);
```

- There is no need to load another js library and make your website slower
- Using jQuery animations takes roughly 10-100 times more processing power than css transitions, this can make your page load jumpy
- When you start from "display: none" , the button won't take up any space and there will be jump on design - that's why I prefer animating opacity
- Remember, that when loading a page (or starting from "display: none") all animations start from completed state

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to do this would probably be using animate.css (https://daneden.github.io/animate.css/). Then it's as simple as adding a class with 'animated' and 'fadeIn' to any element you want to fade in.

Comment: This is so good, i couldnt find anything to do it. normally i dont use css thats probably why i didnt know about this :D

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```js
$("button").click(function() {
  $("#div1").fadeIn();
  $("#div2").fadeIn("slow");
  $("#div3").fadeIn(3000);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<p>Demonstrate fadeIn() with different parameters.</p><button>Click to fade in boxes</button><br><br>
<div id="div1" style="width:80px;height:80px;display:none;background-color:red;"></div><br>
<div id="div2" style="width:80px;height:80px;display:none;background-color:green;"></div><br>
<div id="div3" style="width:80px;height:80px;display:none;background-color:blue;"></div>
```